# How to log data inside an async function?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have this API handler function in my NextJS app. The function works as expected and returns the data from my database. I would like to log some variables inside the function, in particular the req.body object.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    switch (req.method) {
      case "GET": {
        console.log("test log: ", "test");
        const data =
          await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT id, tags::text, geometry::json FROM public.assets LIMIT 5 `;
        if (!data) {
          return res.status(404).json({
            message: "data not found",
          });
        }
        return res.status(200).json(data);
      }
      default:
        return res.status(405).send(`Method ${req.method} not allowed`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res
      .status(403)
      .json({ message: "System error" });
  }
}
```

However logging doesn't work for me, nothing appears in the console, just like if the console.log statement was simply ignored. I've tried logging a "test" string with `console.log("test log: ", "test");`, but to no avail. I have tried moving the console.log statement to different places inside my async function, but it always gets ignored.

How is this behavior explained and how to log data inside this kind of function?

Comment: This will log out to the terminal that where you are running Next (with `npm run start` or `npm run dev`), not the browser console.